# Regex Group not starting with

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm having trouble to compute 2 regex in one (used to deal with .ini files)

I've got this one (I suggest you to use rubular with theses examples to understand)

```
^(?<key>[^=;\r\n]+)=((?<value>\"*.*;*.*\"[^;\r\n]*);?(?<comment>.*)[^\r\n]*)
```

to match :

- This="isnot;acomment"
- This="isa";comment
- This="isa;special";case

And I've got this one :

```
^(?<key>[^=;\r\n]+)=(?<value>[^;\r\n]*);?(?<comment>[^\r\n]*)
```

to match

- This=isasimplecase
- This=isasimple;comment

And I'm trying to merge the 2 regex, sadly I do not manage to say "If my value group is not starting with \" use the second one if not use the first one".

Right now i've got this :

```
^(?<key>[^=;\r\n]+)=(((?<value>\"*.*;*.*\"[^;\r\n]*);?(?<comment>.*)[^\r\n]*)|(?<value>[^;\r\n]*);?(?<comment>[^\r\n]*))
```

But it's creating 2 more sections unnamed for the simple case without quoted. I was thinking that maybe by adding "the first item of the value group for the simple case must not start with \". But I didn't manage to do it.

PS : I suggest you to use rubular to understand better my problem. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
^(?<key>[^=;\r\n]+)=(?<value>"[^"]*"|[^;\n\r]*);?(?<comment>.*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW0mT4/3)

- `(?<key>[^=;\r\n]+)` Matches the part before the `=` symbol.
- `"[^"]*"` Matches the string within the double quotes , ex strings like `"foobar"`. If there is no `"` then the regex engine move on to the next pattern that is `[^;\n\r]*` and it matches upto the first `;` or newline or `\r` character. These matched characters are stored into a named group called `value`.
- `;?` Optional semicolon.
- `(?<comment>.*)` Remaining characters are stored into the `comment` group.

Comment: Thank you bro but it doesn't work with : This="isa;special";case. For this one we should have : <key>This<value>"isa;special"<comment>case this is why I have so much trouble. If there is a ";" inside quote it should not be detected as comment.

Comment: Thank you ! It's perfect. Can you explain me how you did to build the regex ? I'd like to learn how to think to build things like that.